# Bug with column height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have css bug, but can't figure out how to avoid it

http://acrilit.com.ua/page.php?id=13

I'll try

> max-height

it doesn't work

Comment: What is exactly your problem?

Comment: 3rd row strange behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to the different height and width of two images; if all the images have he same height and width, the issue becomes solved.

```
.light-dropshaddow {
  width: 270px;
  height: 202px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a height to the image not a max-height so every thing is the same height and then it will be able to align itself correctly